# How do I create a initializer list for a Q_Object class constructor

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am new to Qt and I can't create a simple Qt class. It's supposed to give me data to create rectangles in QML. Obviously my initializer list is wrong, but I don't understand why and how to fix it. The wrong part in the initializer list is the one where you define the QObject parent.

myclassqt.h:

```
#ifndef MYCLASSQT_H
#define MYCLASSQT_H
#include <QObject>

class myClassQt : public QObject
{
private:
    Q_OBJECT
    int xPosition;
    int yPosition;
    std::string color;
public:
    myClassQt();
    explicit myClassQt(int xPosition, int yPosition, std::string color, QObject *parent = 0);

    int getxPosition();
    int getyPosition();
    std::string getColor();
    void setxPosition(int x);
    void setyPosition(int y);
    void setColor(std::string newColor);
};

#endif // MYCLASSQT_H
```

myclassqt.cpp:

```
#include "myclassqt.h"

myClassQt::myClassQt(int xPosition, int yPosition, std::string color, QObject *parent)
    : xPosition(xPosition), yPosition(yPosition), color(color), parent(*parent)

{

}

int myClassQt::getxPosition(){
    return xPosition;
}

int myClassQt::getyPosition(){
    return yPosition;
}

std::string myClassQt::getColor(){
    return color;
}

void myClassQt::setxPosition(int x){
    xPosition = x;
}

void myClassQt::setyPosition(int y){
    yPosition = y;
}

void myClassQt::setColor(std::string newColor){
    color = newColor;
}
```

Comment: Remove `parent(*parent)` at the end of the initializer list and add `QObject(parent)` at the beginning of it (see [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)).

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. I read through that link that you posted, but I still don't understand how to create a object (into a QList) now though. This is what I tried:
QList<myClassQt> qvec;
qvec.append(myClassQt(1, 1, "red"));

Comment: You can't.  `QObject` is not copy constructible.  Try `QList<myClassQt *>` instead.  You should really edit your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Okay sorry. Next time I will make sure to edit my question. Your answer was very helpful though. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just define copy Constructor of `myClassQt` and get copy everywhere you needed.There is no such a thing that `QObject` is not copyconstructible.When you try `QList<myClassQt>qvec;`it gives an error because of default copy constructor that is generated by Compiler is not viable to be used anymore and Compiler just don't generate that...As a result you are having a C++ class that don't have a copy Constructor at all.You can learn more about copy constructors in [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-constructor-in-cpp/).As an advice, learn c++ basics before trying to learn Qt.

Comment: @Robert.K That is not true. QObjects are not copyable. See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator).

Comment: @JarMan thank you for reply. I'm sorry, my bad, so copy constructor and assignment operator both are disabled(private) by default. But there is also an option of overloading copy constructor, and implementing it to make a clone of the object, not a copy. Overall the solution is to use pointers as it was mentioned in the link you  provided.